# Emacs: switch to buffer with a prefix

Tags: emacs

I have two files, both named `server.pp`. When I switch between buffers I see `server.pp` and `server.pp<1>`. It is the case that one is `module1/server.pp` and the other `module2/server.pp`. How might I switch buffers in such a way as to include some path prefix information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you would want to customize the [uniquify](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Uniquify.html) configuration to change that extra info.  i personally use:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward-angle-brackets)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the options for uniquify-buffer-name-style, please?

Comment: @troutwine - if you load the uniquify module and then run help on the "uniquify-buffer-name-style" variable, it will explain all the options.